# Error while inflating button on a existing view NullPointerException in AnimatorSet.clone

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have an issue creating a Button . The button is supposed to be inserted in a pre-existing layout.

i'm trying to show a button on a video screen. I'm running into following exception . This is only happening on My Device running on Android 7. It works on devices running Android 8+. I'm not sure what is possible wrong with this code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.animation.Animator android.animation.AnimatorSet$Node.mAnimation' on a null object reference
        at android.animation.AnimatorSet.clone(AnimatorSet.java:725)
        at android.animation.AnimatorSet.clone(AnimatorSet.java:682)
        at android.animation.StateListAnimator.clone(StateListAnimator.java:148)
        at android.animation.StateListAnimator$StateListAnimatorConstantState.newInstance(StateListAnimator.java:328)
        at android.animation.StateListAnimator$StateListAnimatorConstantState.newInstance(StateListAnimator.java:327)
        at android.content.res.ConstantState.newInstance(ConstantState.java:53)
        at android.content.res.ConstantState.newInstance(ConstantState.java:61)
        at android.content.res.ConfigurationBoundResourceCache.getInstance(ConfigurationBoundResourceCache.java:40)
        at android.animation.AnimatorInflater.loadStateListAnimator(AnimatorInflater.java:163)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4821)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:113)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:106)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:193)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:496)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at com.abc.minicontroller.aba.onCreateView(Skicontroller.kt:23)
```

This is my code :

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/skip_intro_button"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    tool:text="Skip Recap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal"/>
```

Style :

```
<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ski_background</item>
</style>
```

Selector :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ski_background_selected"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ski_background_default"/>
</selector>
```

Drawable :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <padding android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/gray_opaque"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: The problem does not seem to lie in the code you posted, at least not from what I can tell after successfully compiling and running a test app using your code (on an Android 24 emulator with a compile and targetSDKVersion 26 and a minSDKVersion 24 - Android Studio doesn't let me decrease the compileSDKVersion below 26). Please provide more information about 1. your build.gradle android settings, 2. the other drawable, 3. the animation you use, 4. the Java code you use when inflating the XMLs.

Comment: can you add a parent to the style and try to inflate it?

Answer (score 0):

A) Sharing design patterns will not help since the error is a logical one

B) Look carefully, it's a Null Pointer Exception. So either you're using an API which doesn't have backward compatibility or you're referencing an object which doesn't have any location allocated to it. Since you can run it on Android 8+ it's most probably a lack of backward compatibility issue

C) Use your logs properly to understand where things are going wrong